# Не выводятся все колонки таблицы pandas

Tags: python, pandas, requests

Проблема заключается в следующем. Я создаю запрос к iss moex, получаю данные в формате json, привожу в табличный вид при помощи pandas. Но у меня выводится только последняя колонка

Код:

```
import requests
import apimoex
import pandas as pd

arguments = {'candles.columns': ('open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'value', 'volume', 'begin', 'end')}
start = '0'
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)


with open("C:/Users/User/Desktop/gs/Secidforcb.txt") as secid:    # В этом файле SECID
    s = secid.readlines()
    s = [line.rstrip() for line in s]
    for x in range(len(s)):
        with requests.Session() as session:
            request_url_name = ('http://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/shares/securities/' + s[x] +'/candles.json'
                                '?iss.meta=off&from=2011-11-01&start=' + start + '&candles.columns=open,close,high,low,value,'
                                'volume,begin,end')
            iss = apimoex.ISSClient(session, request_url_name, arguments)
            data = iss.get()
            table = pd.DataFrame(data['candles'])

            print("Акция: ", s[x])
            print(table)
```

Собственно, колонки должны быть как в словаре arguments (open, close, high, low, value, volume, begin, end), но выводится только end. Если я уберу end, то выводится только begin и т.д. Как мне сделать вывод всех колонок?

Файл выглядит ровно так:

```
ABRD
ACKO
AFKS
AFLT
AGRO
AKRN
ALBK
ALNU
ALRS
AMEZ
APTK
AQUA
ARSA
ASSB
AVAN
BANE
BANEP
BELU
BISV
BISVP
BLNG
BRZL
BSPB
CBOM
CHEP
CHGZ
CHKZ
CHMF
CHMK
CNTL
CNTLP
DIOD
DSKY
DVEC
DZRD
DZRDP
EELT
ELTZ
ENPG
ENRU
ETLN
FEES
FESH
FIVE
FIXP
FLOT
GAZA
GAZAP
GAZC
GAZP
GAZS
GAZT
GCHE
GEMA
GLTR
GMKN
GTRK
HALS
HHRU
HIMC
HIMCP
HYDR
IGST
IGSTP
INGR
IRAO
IRGZ
IRKT
ISKJ
JNOS
JNOSP
KAZT
KAZTP
KBSB
```

Пример (data['candles']):

```
{'candles': [{'end': '2014-06-09 10:54:10'}, {'end': '2014-06-09 11:07:16'}, ... {'end': '2014-07-18 11:09:11'}]}
```

Comment: а что у вас в data после iss.get()?

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример данных (`data['candles']`)?

Comment: @strawdog {'candles': [{'end': '2014-06-09 10:54:10'}, {'end': '2014-06-09 11:07:16'}, ... {'end': '2014-07-18 11:09:11'}]}

Comment: @strawdog под многоточием я имел ввиду то, что данные такого же типа только даты другие. data для первого элемента файла ABRD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Колонки надо передать в аргументах одной строкой, а не кортежем отдельных колонок, тогда `API` все колонки возвращает и датафрейм тоже получается правильный:

```
arguments = {'candles.columns': 'open, close, high, low, value, volume, begin, end'}
```

В `table`:

```
    open    close   high    low     value   volume  begin               end
0   132.72  132.77  132.77  132.72  26549   200     2014-06-09 10:50:00 2014-06-09 10:54:10
1   132.70  132.91  132.91  132.70  53122   400     2014-06-09 11:00:00 2014-06-09 11:07:16
...
```